# PHP find require_once real path

Tags: php, require-once, realpath

i need to `require_once` this files `main.class.php` and `functions.php` and `config.php` to `admin/test.php`. how to php find require real path?!

NOTE: `main.class.php` in `class folder` , `functions.php` in `includes folder` and `config.php` in `root` directory and `test.php` in `admin folder`.

File Directory:

```
root
    /admin/
        ->test.php 
    /class/
        ->main.class.php
    /includes/
        ->functions.php
    /templates
    config.php
    phpinfo.php
```

Comment: why not put `/root` into your include_path, then it's just `require('class/main.class.php')` and so on?

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV: yeap! I'm looking for the best way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add your `root` folder to the include path and work from there.

From `admin/test.php`

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(__DIR__ . '/..'),
    get_include_path()
)));

require_once 'class/main.class.php';
require_once 'includes/functions.php';
require_once 'config.php';
```

### Update

If I'm following your question correctly, assuming you wanted to define this in the `config.php` file, you would do something like this

#### config.php

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    __DIR__,
    get_include_path()
)));

require_once 'class/main.class.php';
require_once 'includes/functions.php';
```

#### admin/test.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../config.php';
```

Comment: this useful and pretty answer. can/how to put your method in 'define' and put in config file then in myfiles?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution not depending on the $_SERVER variable:

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/../class/main.class.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/../includes/functions.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/../config.php');
```

Comment: FYI, the `__DIR__` magic constant has been around since 5.3.0. `__DIR__ === dirname(__FILE__)`

Answer (score 0):

From `admin/test.php` you would require like this:

```
require_once("../class/main.class.php");
require_once("../includes/functions.php");
require_once("../config.php");
```

Comment: Not at all and do not see it as an attack. I just did not understand what you meant. Relax : )