# Accessing parent folder in PHP on XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

For a while I've been testing projects on a server and then uploading it to the correct folders. Recently I decided to try using XAMPP for increased security and less hassle when testing; so I installed it, imported the database and copied the files to the `htdocs` folder.

Includes and requires seem to be working fine, but the one instance where it fails is when I try to access a parent folder, i.e. `require "../file.php";`. I tried playing around a bit with the `include_path` variable in `php.ini`, but nothing seems to be working.

- I'm using Windows 10
- XAMPP's version is 3.2.2

Any idea on what could be causing this, and how to fix it?

Many thanks in advance.

---

## Edit:

The file structure goes like this:

`folderA/folderB/folderC`

What I try to do is...

1. Have a file (`fileA`) in `folderA` that includes a file (`fileC`) in `folderC`
2. The file (`fileC`) in `folderC` includes a file (`fileB`) in `folderB`

Where apache seems to fail is when including `fileB` from `fileC`.

The code is as follows:

in `fileA.php`: `include "folderB/folderC/fileC.php";`

in `fileC.php`: `require "../fileB.php";`

My `include_path` currently looks like this: `include_path= ".;D:\xampp\htdocs\"`

Comment: whats the error?? add some code where you are struct

Comment: Warning: require(../file.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\parent\file.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../main.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\htdocs\parent') in D:\xampp\htdocs\parent\file.php on line 2

Comment: `require __DIR__ . '/../file.php';` See http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: it would be better if you add your folder structure

Comment: It is as follows:

`outer/inner`

I have the main.php file inside "inner", where it requires a file in "outer".

Comment: @Phil I'm trying to see if I can find an answer that doesn't modify the code, since it works fine on the live server. It only doesn't work on XAMPP.

Comment: it is working fine on my local environment on xampp :)

Comment: Crazy thought, is there a `D:\xampp\htdocs\main.php` file? `include_path` also typically includes `.`, as in the current working directory. Do you have a reason for removing it?

Comment: I've updated the question with a more "concise" description of the issue.

Comment: What **exactly** do the `require` / `include` lines look like in `fileA` and `fileC`. Also, what **exactly** is your `include_path` set to?

Comment: FYI, relying on the environment configuration to correctly include files is bad and makes your application less portable. I strongly suggest changing your code to use absolute paths (via `__DIR__`) and / or setting the `include_path` based on an absolute path known to your app (again, `__DIR__`)

Comment: @Phil edited, thank you.

Comment: Because your entry point is `fileA`, the `.` in the `include_path` refers to `folderA`. From that point on, any relative include path in **any included file** is relative to `folderA`. Are you beginning to see why this is not ideal?

Comment: I understand, thank you. I'll definitely append `__DIR__` to the paths; but how should the include_path be structured to include the files within?

Comment: @Mergan you could set it to some logical point of entry. The `include_path` is a FIFO stack so set the best options first. Say you set it to `folderA`, you could then use `include 'folderB/folderC/fileC';` and `include 'folderB/fileB';`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752625/php-find-require-once-real-path/15752693#15752693

Comment: I've set the `include_path` as `folderA` per your recommendation, and modified the require to `folderB/fileB`. It works like a charm, thank you. Please set it as the Answer so I can accept it.